# Cummincating with a thread(callable) that has an infinite loop

Tags: java, multithreading, event-handling, thread-safety

I have defined a class(callable) named "folderwatcher" that is monitoring a specific folder for any changes. The main code is in an infinite loop similar to:  [Monitor a Directory for Changes using Java](http://www.venishjoe.net/2009/10/monitor-directory-for-changes-using.html). I want the method/class that calls this "folderwatcher" to listen for any events discovered by the "folderwatcher" and does some operations based on the event. Does anyone know how I can do this? Do I need an event handler? any examples?
thanks

Comment: can you work with Java 7? It has build in stuff for this

Comment: @Eugene The code in the link is already using Java 7 WatchService API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, it is wrong to use an infinite loop approach. if you are really using `Callable`  then you are already using an `ExecutorService`. What you should use is a `ScheduledExecutorService` and schedule your code as a repeated task.

As far as an event handler, this is not hard to accomplish, for example:

```
interface FileDetectedHandler { void fileDetected(File f); }

public static void main(String[] args) {
  final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = 
     Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
  final FileDetectedHandler h = new FileDetectedHandler(File f) {
    public void fileDetected(File f) {
      System.out.format("File detected: %s\n", f);
  }};
  final Runnable r = new Runnable() { public void run() {
    File f = null;
    //detect file
    if (f != null) h.fileDetected(f);
  }};
  scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(r, 0, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Comment: thx for the example, could be please give me more details of the code. i am not really a pro in java. thx

Comment: There is really not much more to it. I've updated with the two ExecutorService API calls, this is now a full example except for the file detection code that you already have.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik You probably meant: `scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(...)`.

Comment: @assylias Thanks, corrected (WithFixedDelay makes slightly more sense so I'll use that).

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik the problem with ur approach is that, when I add/delete several files together to/from the "monitored" folder, it can only detect one operation for just one file. can you please help me that also?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: i mean, as you said I removed the infinite loop and followed ur approach. now this happens.

Comment: Well, post another question with your code included and I or someone else will be probably able to help you further.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12077391/how-to-monitor-a-folder-for-changes-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Use a callback.  This can be done by implementing a synchronised method on the parent object and then pass a reference to the parent object into the runnable object's constructor.  The runnable can then call the method on the parent to notify it of something.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)

Comment: @Hossein - "callback" and "callable" are not the same thing!

Comment: Callback - different concept.